# Hide your text with colorful blocks in secret(-mode)

Tags: lisp, elisp

### Motivation

While working on a completely unrelated task, I wanted to share a screenshot of my current Emacs frame, but *not* of the actual text contents. And while GIMP's pixelate filter did the job, I didn't want to fire up my image manipulation program just to share a picture of a custom theme or some functionality.

I thought that Emacs *must* have some functionality to hide certain information on the displayed text. I remembered `toggle-rot13-mode`, but anyone interested in the text could decrypt it rather quickly. So instead, I had a look into its implementation and put my Emacs Lisp hat on to find my own solution.

### Screenshot

On the left, the original buffer. On the right, an indirect clone with `secret-mode` enabled.

[image: screenshot of secret-mode]

<sup>(Note: this is the `wombat` theme, with *Fira Code* in Emacs 27.2 on Windows.)</sup>

### Code

I'm using two code blocks here to keep the noise from the actual lisp implementation. The actual code is just a single lisp file (`secret-mode.el`).

```lisp
;;; secret-mode.el --- hide text in buffer           -*- lexical-binding: t; -*-

;; Copyright (C) 2021  (omitted*)

;; Author:  (omitted*)
;; Keywords: games
;; Version: 0.0.1

;; This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
;; it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
;; the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
;; (at your option) any later version.

;; This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
;; but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
;; MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
;; GNU General Public License for more details.

;; You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
;; along with this program.  If not, see <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
```

```lisp
;;; Commentary:

;; This package provides `secret-mode', a buffer-local mode that uses
;; `buffer-display-table' to replace the displayed glyphs with Unicode
;; blocks.

;;; Code:

(defconst secret-mode-table
  (let ((disptbl (make-display-table)))
    (dotimes (i 1024)
      (aset disptbl i
            (pcase (get-char-code-property i 'general-category)
              ((or 'Cc 'Cf 'Zs 'Zl 'Zp) nil)
              ('Lu (vector (make-glyph-code ?▆)))
              (_   (vector (make-glyph-code ?▃))))))
    disptbl)
  "Display table for the command `secret-mode'.")

;;;###autoload
(define-minor-mode secret-mode
  "Hide text."
  :lighter " Secret"
  (if secret-mode
      (setq buffer-display-table secret-mode-table)
    (setq buffer-display-table nil)))

(provide 'secret-mode)
;;; secret-mode.el ends here
```

### What I'm looking for

Any kind of feedback is welcome. Feel free to trash the use of Display Tables if its unidiomatic or if there is a more practical way with another feature.

Since I'm pretty happy with the result, I would like to publish this package, so feel especially encouraged to point anything out that needs to be done beforehand, as it will be my first published package.

Comment: Looks good to me - sorry I don't have any suggestions to improve it!

Comment: @TobySpeight Still: thanks for the feedback! :)

Comment: Very nice utility. Also don't find anything to improve :)